# UIPageViewController lags on swipe because of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift2, uipageviewcontroller

So I'm trying to build an app where you can swipe between three views that are the size of the screen, each of which has its own UITableView. At first I did it with a UIScrollView, but it seemed too heavy memory-wise, so I decided to change the structure for a PageViewController with three child view controllers.

The problem I have now is that I get a lag when I swipe: when I first arrive on the middle view controller (which is what the app is supposed to do), if I swipe right or left, I have like a half second freeze and then it works normally. From there, if I swipe back and forth between this view controller and the central one, it works perfectly, since ViewControllerBeforeViewController and ViewControllerAfterViewController have already returned the viewControllers.

But when I try to go to the third one, I get the lag again. Basically if my pageViewController had two child controllers, it would be fine, but the fact that there is a third one means that at some point I have to return a new one, which takes time.

I'm thinking I should pre-load the controller, but doesn't defeat the purpose of switching from UIScrollView to UIPageViewController? How do apps do when they have a tutorial that has more than two pages, or how does snapchat do it?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem as you. I have four pages in which all of them have table views. But the lag only happens on iPhone 4. When I run it on iPhone 5 or higher spec iPhones, it went smooth.

Comment: Interesting, I am indeed running on iPhone4, I just tried on iPhone 5 and though I still see a little lag, it definitely works a lot better. Curious to know the reason.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: problem solved?